# FileMaker Pro Standard/Advanced users connection limits to a FileMaker Server with Team License

Tags: filemaker

Is there a limit in quantity of FileMaker Pro Standard/Advanced users where connection to a FileMaker Server with Team License is involved?
I mean that if a company choose the FileMaker Server with 5 license for User Connection, I may be the sixth to be connected with my standard FileMaker Pro Advanced with no problem (I work this way at my customer sites) but which is the limit for quantity of user connected, if any, at server side?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a use/licensing question for a third-party software product and not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. Contact the software manufacturer for information regarding use and licensing questions regarding their product. We are not their licensing support department. This site is for questions relating to programming (code) and use of programmers tools (IDEs, compilers, version control systems, etc.).

Comment: Sorry! In my mind this is more a technical question than licensing because the license limit is well defined. Should I delete it?

Comment: It's off-topic here. It's a licensing question (*What am I allowed/able to do with this license?*). Anything not programming related is off-topic, and the question you've asked has nothing to do with programming. Off-topic questions tend to attract downvotes, and negatively scored questions (even if they're later deleted) can have a detrimental impact on your account here, even months down the road.

Comment: You are the master, with 101'933 reputation, and may say what is right and what is not. Can you help me to decide what to do at the best? Either delete the question through the "delete" button under my question or something different?

Comment: By accepting the answer, you've removed the ability to delete the post (you can't delete a post with an accepted answer). You've already decided what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry again but, let me say that I asked immediately what to do at the best and you missed to confirm me that the "delete" button should have been the right way. In the meantime the answer of AndreasT was making clear my question and I gave him the acceptance.
I will learn and I hope I will recover in the future. Best wishes and thanks for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit of 5 pertains to the ones connecting using the team license. For regular Pro/Advanced licenses there is no limit, other than the physical limits imposed by the server software/hardware combination. Check the FileMaker Server specification at filemaker.com for those limits.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a use/licensing question for a third-party software product and not a programming question as defined in the help center guidelines.

The licensing that's been implemented for FM in the past few years has been constantly changing and difficult to understand.

Typically FM developers don't just "code" they often do EVERYTHING from sales to business analysis, back end data design, front end interface design, server implementation, testing and commissioning, documentation and end-user training. Getting the licensing right is a big part of that.

So while it's not a programming question, it's definitely a "stuff I need to know about FileMaker" question.